# How to work around visualeditor not working on iphone

Tags: tinymce, plone

Visual editors such as kupu and tinymce don't allow you to type when used on an iphone. In Plone HTML view still works but the user will have to know html syntax. Is there any better work around?

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that most modern mobile phones (with a few exceptions) do support web browsing with a limited functionality only. Functionality that is necessary in order to use kupu and tinymce. Plone HTML is a good approach. You might have a very simplified html element description on that page or linked with the very few elements a user needs.

Answer (score 0):

Plone supports plain text and restructured text (same as Sphinx docs) in rich text input also.

This is enabled for the default Page content type, though the option has been hidden in the latest Plone versions I think.

What you would need to do is to write a plug-in which monkey-patches rich text field to force the input to to be plain text/restructured text on mobile browsers.

Web and Mobile provides some facilities for this, to see whether a HTTP request is from a mobile user agent (mobile.sniffer package)

http://webandmobile.mfabrik.com/

Comment: How feasible is it to create content with reST via a phone and then have it auto convert to a rich text editor when you edit later via the web?

I looked at webandmobile and didn't see that it provided an out of the box solution to mobile content creation. Would be a nice feature (hint hint) :)

Comment: Not easy. TinyMCE doesn't support it. Also webandmobile does not support mobile content creation currently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm attempting to do the same thing on my DroidX with Plone 4.0.5.  I've tried the default Browser, Dolphin, Opera Mini, Opera Mobile, Firefox 4, and Firefox 5.  So far Rich Text fields do not work in the default Browser, Dolphin, Opera Mini, Opera Mobile.  I got close in Firefox 4 and 5 as I could enter text but just not "see" it properly. However, Firefox 4 and 5 are buggy and locked up when I attempted to use them.

The way I got around this problem was to turn off javascript in your mobile browser and then when you edit your content use either Plain Text, Markdown, or type in the raw HTML into the place where the Rich Text field is supposed to be.  I could successfully enter text this way in the default Android Browser and Dolphin.